# Using "union struct" to avoid cast/box/unbox

Tags: c#, jit, cil

In a certain context I need to manage constrained values. To simplify; let's just say that I need to constrain values to either be a string or a 64-bit integer.

For this purpose; I'm considering declaring a struct type that has one field for the type of value being stored and one field for the actual value.

In this simplified case, the type field could perhaps be omitted because we could distinguish string and integer by their CLR type. However; I need the type field for other purposes (more than one "constrained value type" can be represented by a single CLR type).

A straight forward approach:

```
public struct MyValue
{
    private object _value;
    private MyValueType _type;

    public string String
    {
        get
        {
            // todo: check type
            return (string)_value;
        }

        set
        {
            // todo: validate value
            _type = MyValueType.String;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public long Int64
    {
        get
        {
            // todo: check type
            return (long)_value;
        }

        set
        {
            // todo: validate value
            _type = MyValueType.Int64;
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this approach requires some "extra" IL instructions:

- String-getter need a `castclass` instruction to cast from object to string.
- Int64-getter need an `unbox.any` instruction to cast from object to long.
- Int64-setter need a `box` instruction to cast from long to object.

The purpose of this struct is to enforce constraints, so by the time its getting or setting a value it is known that it'll be of the right type.

Therefore I'm considering using [FieldOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes. Something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MyValue
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private string _string;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private long _int64;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    private MyValueType _type;

    public string String
    {
        get
        {
            // todo: check type
            return _string;
        }

        set
        {
            // todo: validate value
            _type = MyValueType.String;
            _string = value;
        }
    }

    public long Int64
    {
        get
        {
            // todo: check type
            return _int64;
        }

        set
        {
            // todo: validate value
            _type = MyValueType.Int64;
            _int64 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach there are no extra box, unbox, or cast instructions. Which makes me think that this approach is better.

Question is: **Are there any drawbacks to using explict struct layout and field offset attributes?**

Perhaps there the JIT-compiler would choke on this for some reason?

---

In real code; the struct would be immutable. The fields would be read-only and it would not have any setters.

First, I didn't think this would make a difference, since it would just more or less mean that the setters would move into constructors, one for each value type.

However; the compiler requires that **all** struct members are initialized by a constructor – without regard that they have the same field offset.

I need to do something like this:

```
public MyValue(string value)
{
    // todo: validate value
    _int64 = 0; // just to satisfy the compiler
    _string = value;
    _type = MyValueType.String;
}

public MyValue(long value)
{
    // todo: validate value
    _string = null; // just to satisfy the compiler
    _int64 = value;
    _type = MyValueType.Int64;
}
```

This means that the second approach require "extra" IL instructions too. There are three extra instructions for "defaulting" each field that won't be used.

For example: Setting `_string = null` yield `ldarg.0`, `ldnull` and `stfld`.

These extra instructions are completely wasteful. And it would get worse if I would add additional fields.

So; question is also: **Will the JIT-compiler be smart enough to disregard these wasteful instructions?**

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: If you mean the type itself - it would provide a common way of working with these constrained values. Which is important in this case. If you mean fiddling with IL instructions - that's more for fun and because I care about the details.

Comment: Why not store long in one field and string in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. It seems that this can't be done anyway. Trying to load such a type will cause a `TypeLoadException` saying something like

> Could not load type 'MyValue' from assembly 'MyAssembly' because it contains **an object field** at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or **overlapped by a non-object field**.

So, I guess it is not possible to have a reference type field on the same offset as a value type field.

End of story.

I'm leaving this Q&A (not deleting) though in case anyone else is curious.

Comment: CLR wouldn't usually let you read the real value of an object reference (which could be done this way, had it worked), and won't trust you enough to allow you to do this, even if your intentions are good.